# react-native login with Instagram android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, instagram-api

I am trying to login with Instagram in React-native for android.
For [Ios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-instagram-oauth/)
this is availabe.
What about android?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0

Comment: do you find solution for this?

Comment: Were you able to make it?